# Why is my webform not displaying?

Tags: 6, webforms

I have a webform. If I go into the backend "content management => content" area and click "edit" for the form and then "preview", the form preview displays fine.

However, if I view that same webform on the frontend, I see either:

1. "Published by admin on Tue, 07/19/2011 - 15:15" if I am logged in as a new user
2. "Published by admin..." and in my $messages "You have already submitted this form. View your previous submissions." if I am logged in as a user who has submitted the form before.

This form was displaying fine at some point. Obviously someone working on the project (quite likely me) has broken it since then.

The form is published. The submission limit is set to "unlimited". The "status of this form" is set to "open". The "submission access" settings allow any "authenticated user" to submit the form.

What are some reasons for why my form might not be displaying? Do I need to add something in my page.tpl.php to have it display? What's the quickest way for me to debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like something you could have done in the node template in your theme. You can try to change your theme. If that fixes then your theme is the root cause.

Comment: Theme swapping is always a good 'super quick' test for this type of error.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out to be a silly mistake in node.tpl.php — someone removed the `print $content;` from that file.

Comment: Hi，I have a same bug with drupal6 handover project，the form show before,after sometimes login&logout， I miss the webform&node body！in back-end of pages of panle,there's content body work well.
when print debug info,I know before,the webform-form-1363.tpl.php is work,but after not work.

Comment: somethimes,the bug disappear after restart my computer. 
clear cache didn't work,
restart apache didn't work